# Replace Null Values in <String, String[]> TreeMap

Tags: java, arrays, treemap

I have a tree map of the form: < String, String[] >

There are values inside of my String[] that are null. When writing my results to a file, using the below code, I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My current code for writing to my file is below, I'm trying to replace the nulls with an empty string.

```
        new File(outFolder).mkdir();
        File dir = new File(outFolder);
        //get the file we're writing to
        File outFile = new File(dir, "javaoutput.txt");

        //create a writer
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(outFile), "utf-8"))) { 
            for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : allResults.entrySet()) {
                writer.write(entry.getKey() + " "+ Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()).replace(null, ""));
                writer.newLine(); 

            }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are supposed to loop on the array and replace the nulls with empty strings *before* you convert it to a string. There are no `null` inside a string, only the string n-u-l-l, and you don't want to replace that because valid words like `nullify` will also be changed.

Comment: Another option would be not to have nulls there in the first place. Maybe you should explain why you have nulls in arrays where you don't want there to be nulls, and fix it at the origin instead of after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue arises from this method call: `replace(null,"");`

Check the implementation of `replace()`

The first parameter it takes is a `CharSequence` and the first thing it does with this char sequence is call `toString()` on it.

This is going to throw a `NullPointerException` every time.

`Arrays.toString()` however will replace `null` values with `"null"` so change your call to replace to be: `replace("null", "");`

Comment: And if you check the implementation of [static] method `toString()` in class `Arrays`, you will see that it converts null array elements to the string `null`. Hence if the OP wants to replace null elements in the array then the first argument in the call to method `replace()` should be the string "null".

Comment: @abra, `"null"`, perhaps, definitely not `null`. And also, what if one of the *good* elements is the word "nullify" or a similar string? The replacement should be before making it into a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. This resolved my issue!